# I want to open websites through shellexecute() by variable by assigning the variable with web-address in c

Tags: c, windows, web, shellexecute

I want to open a webpage through shellexecute() in c.
shellexecute() works fine if I give the web-address before but if I wanted to change that web-address,what should I do?

Here the example:

`ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "rundll32.exe", "url.dll,FileProtocolHandler http://www.google.com",NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL);`

But what if i wanted to open http://facebook.com ? Is there a way to dynamically assign wed-address like including a variable in shellexecute() or any other method?

So finally is there a way to replace the actual web-address in shellexecute() with a variable that we will assign?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where is the function 'ShellExecute' to be found?

Comment: In widows.h header file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the URL by updating a variable, but you can do it by simply calling ShellExecute again with your new URL. From Microsoft's [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/224816):

> Call the ShellExecute API and pass it a URL. That is the easiest way
> for you to start the default Web browser from your application. If the
> default Web browser currently runs, ShellExecute tells the instance
> that runs to go to your Uniform Resource Locator (URL). If it is not
> running, ShellExecute starts the application and then browses to your
> URL.

The wording is slightly odd, but it says that when you call ShellExecute() it will launch the default browser if it is not running and send it to your URL, but if the default browser is already running, it will just redirect it to the URL you passed.

Comment: yes, we can!

After some tries I got by changing the above code to--- 
shellexecute(NULL,str,"%s",NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL);

And you can assign any URL to "str" (which will be string").

It works!

Comment: Well, I guess I stand corrected, kudos to you. ;-) Just one thing to be aware of though, I can't find anything in Microsoft's documentation indicating it should work this way. Maybe I just missed it, but you also might be relying here on a side effect that could change in a future update or release. Or maybe not, but it's something to consider. Is there any reason you can't just call ShellExecute() again as documented each time you want to change the URL?